# Perl REST client, authentication issue

Tags: perl, rest, perl-module, perl5.16

I am using Perl 5.16 with [`REST::Client`](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Client) for REST call with GET, but it shows an error 401 authentication issue. I am not clear how to resolve this issue.

**Code**

```
use REST::Client;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;
use MIME::Base64;

my $username = 'test';
my $password = 'test';

my $client = REST::Client->new();
$client->setHost('http://myurl');

my $headers = {
    Accept        => 'application/json',
    Authorization => 'Full' . encode_base64($username . ':' . $password)
};
$client->GET('folder/file', $headers);

print $client->responseCode();
print $client->responseContent();
```

Comment: @borodin you invented a new tag!

Comment: @simbabque: I did! You can share it if you like

Comment: I don't know if it's like that in your real code, but `folder/file` should be `/folder/file`

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are doing [HTTP Basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). For that, you need to have your header as follows:

```
Authorization: Basic foobar
```

Where `foobar` is the base64 representation of `username:password`.

In Perl, that gives:

```
my $headers = {
  Accept => 'application/json',  
  Authorization => 'Basic ' . encode_base64($username . ':' . $password)
  #                      ^ note the space here                      
};
```

---

Note that [HTTP::Headers also provides a method to set HTTP Basic authentication](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Headers#h-authorization_basic). Unfortunately that's not directly accepted by REST::Client.

Comment: I tried with above, but getting an error HTTP Status 401  Bad credentials</h1><b>message</b> This request requires HTTP authentication

Comment: Now is the time to learn what those HTTP status codes mean. Your password is wrong.

Comment: Using this login credentials I can GET using Chrome advance REST Client.

Comment: Look at the header that produces, take the base64 encoded string from there and compare.

Comment: Hi Simbabque, user name and password is correct. I have checked and this is defined in variable my $username = 'test';
my $password = 'test';

Comment: @sen did you compare the base64 or just the pain user name and password? Of course those need to be correct, but the server sees them in a different way. Just must look at that.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and found that I had to tell encode_base64 to not break up the response string e.g encode_base64($username . ':' . $password, "")