# Perl requests GET via Redfish

Tags: perl, odata

i only find examples for Python to GET infos via redfish.
Here is my Perl Code Snippet that i already got:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MIME::Base64;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long;
use REST::Client;

my $client = REST::Client->new(host => $host);
my $encoded_auth = encode_base64("$user:$password", '');

 # Get the incident with sys_id declared above
 $client->GET("/redfish/v1",
              {'Authorization' => "Basic $encoded_auth",
               'Accept' => 'application/json'});

my $perlScalar = decode_json $client->responseContent();
print Dumper $client->responseContent();
```

I get a empty string from Dumper, so i think the connect is not correct. This Script is functional against a HP REST API Device.

I really dont understand how to do this, with ::JSON Module.. perhaps someone of you got already done  this?

Kind Regards

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40153367/edit) to add the output you get from adding `print Dumper $client->responseContent()` to your code. It seems that what you're getting back isn't valid JSON.

Comment: Hi i edited my post, thank you!

Comment: What does `$client->responseCode` contain? There's a [similar discussion here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516238/perl-rest-client-authentication-issue) but it doesn't look like they found a solution.

Comment: `$client->responseCode` seems to be an empty string..

Comment: With the fix from Dave i got a big step forward, i get: `'Can\'t connect to 10.0.0.1:443 (certificate verify failed)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this bug report for REST::Client](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=65804) which seems relevant.

> If you don't set Follow to true then the module uses LWP::UserAgent's
>   simple_request method. This means authentication does not work.

Looking at the module's documentation, it seems likely that the fix is to add

```
$client->setFollow(1);
```

before you try to use the client.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the tipp!! But i get: `Can't locate object method "SetFollow" via package "REST::Client"`

Comment: @msrDigit Sorry. That's a typo. It's `setFollow()`, not `SetFollow()`. Fixed now.

Comment: I hoped i found someone who got already a solution for this, because i dont really understand the usage of theses Modules. Before i waste more time of yours, i can use the python Script to connect and give it over to Perl...

Comment: @msrDigit: Are you saying that this fix doesn't work? In that case I'm all out of ideas, I'm afraid.

Comment: oh cool, now i got the error `LWP::Protocol::https::Socket: SSL connect attempt failed error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify`

Comment: I don't have time to investigate further but Googling '[perl lwp::protocol::https "SSL connect attempt failed"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=perl+lwp%3A%3Aprotocol%3A%3Ahttps+%22SSL+connect+attempt+failed%22) gives plenty of things to try.

Comment: Hi tested some things without success. I Think it is somthing about the oData authentication. I will keep you informed..